# Defining KeyboardAccelerator ScopeOwner inside Listview's DataTemplate

Tags: c#, winui-3

In my WinUI 3 app I have 2 list views that use the same datatemplate. I have defined MenuFlyoutItems and KeyboardAccelerator in each.

When the keyboard key is pressed the KeyboardAccelerator's Click event handler is called with the selected item in the first list view always although I may have pressed the keys in the second list view.

I think defining the ScopeOwner is the answer. But I am unable to do so inside the DataTemplate.

What is the way to get the event handler called from the second list view?

```
<MenuFlyoutItem Text="Explore here" Click="ResourceContextMenu_Item_Click" Tag="ExploreHereCommand">
    <MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
          <KeyboardAccelerator Key="E" Modifiers="Control"/>                                       
    </MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
</MenuFlyoutItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by getting the focused element which returns a ListViewItem. And then I get the ListView using the VisualTreeHelper.

In the below code rootGrid is just the name of the top most level grid in the Xaml file. It is important to send the XamlRoot paramenter as described in this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/3484

```
private ListView GetActiveResourceListView()
        {
            object focusedElement = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(rootGrid.XamlRoot);

            if (focusedElement == null) return null;

            if (focusedElement is ListViewItem)
            {
                DependencyObject o = ((FrameworkElement)focusedElement).FindAscendant<ListView>();

                if (o != null)
                {
                    return o as ListView;
                }
            }

            if (focusedElement is ListView)
            {
                return focusedElement as ListView;    
            }

            return null;
        }
```